# Formula for combinations involving product notation?

Tags: products

So after looking at the factorial formula and learning about product notation, I recognized this relation between them: $$\prod_{n=1}^kn=k!$$
And after fooling around and doing some trial and error, I came up with a similar relation for permutations:
$$\prod_{n=r}^{k}n = (_kP_{k-r+1}) = P(k,k-r+1)$$

But when it came to combinations, the only formula I was able to create was this: $$\frac{1}{(k-r+1)!}\prod_{n=r}^{k}n = (_kC_{k-r+1}) = {k \choose k-r+1}$$
So my question is are there any formulas for combinations that only involve a product notation? That is, an equation using product notation without having to multiply out front by $\frac{1}{(k-r+1)!}$? Thanks for any answers

Comment: your first one is $k!$

Comment: Oh my! Thanks for that typo. I'll fix that

Comment: You have already shown how to rewrite a factorial using product notation. Try replacing the factorial in the denominator with it's product notation representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, I actually had to write the below section for a short proof I wrote. Hopefully this helps.

In combinatorics, the choose function asks the question of 'Given a set of $n$ elements, in how many ways can one make a subset of $k$ elements from it'. It is defined as the following.

\begin{equation}
    \binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k!)}
\end{equation}

Now, it will be helpful to rewrite this using product notation. As a quick refresher, the product notation works like sigma notation, but for multiplication. It is defined as the following.

\begin{equation}
    \prod_{i=1}^{n}{f(n)}=f(1)\times f(2)\times f(3)\times f(4)\times ...\times f(n)
\end{equation}

Now, of course, the factorial function is simply the product of all natural numbers up to an input $n$. Now, let us see how we can write the fraction $\frac{n!}{k!}$ in product notation. In order to motivate this, it will help to look at a numerical example. Let us examine the case of $\frac{12!}{7!}$. This is really equal to the following.

\begin{equation}
    \frac{12!}{7!}=\frac{12\times 11\times 10\times 9\times 8\times 7\times 6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{7\times 6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{12!}{7!}=8\times 9\times 10\times 11\times 12
\end{equation}

Now, let us subtract seven from all these elements, getting the sequence $1,2,3,4,5$. Thus, we can say the following.

\begin{equation}
    \frac{12!}{7!}=\prod_{i=1}^{12-7}{7+i}
\end{equation}

Thus, generalizing this case, we can state the following.

\begin{equation}
    \frac{n!}{k!}=\prod_{i=1}^{n-k}{k+i}
\end{equation}

Now, let us look at the final piece in the combination definition. The factorial of $(n-k)$ is simply the following.

\begin{equation}
    (n-k)!=\prod_{i=1}^{n-k}{i}
\end{equation}

Now, we can divide the two previous products to say the following.

\begin{equation}
    \binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n-k}{k+i}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-k}{i}}
\end{equation}

Furthermore, because the indexes of both products are the same, we can divide their core function, getting the following.

\begin{equation}
    \binom{n}{k}=\prod_{i=1}^{n-k}{\frac{k+i}{i}}
\end{equation}